# virtual network interfaces multiple vpn connections

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I have 2 vpn connections and I want to be able to connect on both of them at the same time, running Fedora 18. My main idea was to run VirtualBox with 2 virtual machines, connect each of them on the VPN and then SSH to each machine to access both VPNs. But then I thought there must be a way to do it in one machine. I mean there's no point of running a whole operating system just to get 1 connection.

I am aware of nm-tool but I think if I connect a VPN it "wraps" all the connections. Is that right? Is there a way to create, lets say, `eth1` `eth2` or `eth0:1` `eth0:2` and assign 1 VPN on each?

If there is no possible way of doing it in one machine and I have to stick to the VM solution, what configuration would you recommend to use less hardware resources? (distribution, ram assigned, etc.) hence if I stick to the VM solution I would only need the VM for the connection and nothing else.

(Any solutions are accepted, but I prefer command line if possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vpnc`.  This does not wrap all connections, but adds a new interface for the vpn.

You will create a new file in `/etc/vpnc/` for each configuration.  There is a `default.conf` file as an example, with everything commented out.

If you have `vpn1.conf` and `vpn2.conf` in that directory, you'll start the vpns with the commands `vpnc vpn1` and `vpnc vpn2` (or perhaps something like `vpnc --enable-1des vpn1` -- see the manual page for `vpnc`).

I recommend making `/etc/resolv.conf` immutable when using `vpnc` as it will overwrite it.  I usually don't want the vpn dns, and if you have two, it is sure to be unhelpful.

Comment: thx a lot for your reply. My bad i should mention i am using openvpn. But your answer made me understand it's a vpn client issure rather than os issue. So i can do something like: 
`sudo openvpn --mktun --dev tun2`
`sudo ip link set tun2 up`
ifconfig now gives a tun2

found this information here:
[link]http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/